# "AssertionError:You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method

Tags: bert-language-model, word-embedding, transfer-learning

"You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method"
An encoding is the output of one of the encoding methods of the tokenizer, i.e. **call**/encode_plus/batch_encode_plus.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.